# how to match all files containing word1 AND word2 across different lines with ag or rg (PCRE/Rust regex)

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, ag

I've long list of generated reports which I want to filter. The report is something like this:

```
Report Name
Report Date
Blah blah blah
Blah: WORD1
Blah blah
blah blah: WORD2
blah blah
```

I'm trying to use ag (PCRE regex) or rg (rust regex) and find all files which contains WORD1 AND WORD2 in different places of the file (contains new line).

I've already search SX and found these which didn't work:

```
> ag (?=.*WORD1)(?=.*WORD2)

> ag (?=.*WORD1)((.|\n)*)(?=.*WORD2)
```

---

#### UPDATE

As @WiktorStribiżew pointed out, the ag uses PCRE. Sorry for the mistake.

my expected output is:

```
blah blah: WORD2
```

or just the list of matched files.

---

p.s. currently I've managed to using this:

```
> ag "WORD2" $(ag -l "WORD1")
```

Comment: What is your expected output please

Comment: Why look aheads. Can you not do: `WORD1[\s\S]*WORD2`

Comment: @anubhava One drawback of that is that it assumes an order between the two words.  Not that this may actually matter for the OP.

Comment: Try [`(?s)^(?=.*WORD1)(?=.*WORD2).*\n\K(?-s).*WORD2`](https://regex101.com/r/KuNJ1c/1) with Ag. Note Ag uses PCRE, not Perl regex.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, Thanks it works. Could you please make your comment an answer and write a bit of elaboration on its mechanism?.

Comment: @anubhava, thanks but it isn't a real AND as Tim Biegeleisen pointed it out.

Comment: ok in  that case use: [`^(?=[\s\S]*WORD1)(?:[\s\S]*\n)?\K.*WORD2`](https://regex101.com/r/18BiHE/1)

Comment: @anubhava, thanks. I think the better answer is the one which could be easily extended to 3 and more matches.

Comment: `3 or matches` You should update the question with more clarity.

Comment: Yes, you're right the question is originally set for two matches and yours and Wiktor's pretty do the job. But I think it would be good to generalize the case for more matches. I'll create another question. Thanks.

Comment: This seems like an over-complication? `ag WORD2 | ag WORD1` or `rg WORD2 | rg WORD1` both work fine.

Comment: @BurntSushi5, That doesn't work for me but `ag "ShowThis" $(ag -l "WORD1" $(ag -l "WORD2"))` works.

Comment: `ag ShowThis | ag WORD1 | ag WORD2` will yield every line that contains `ShowThis` and `WORD1` and `WORD2`.

Comment: @BurntSushi5, that's the problem. WORD1 and WORD2 and "showThis" all are different lines each.

Comment: @SdidS Ah I see now. Mea culpa!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use a PCRE pattern with `ag`:

```
(?s)^(?=.*WORD1)(?=.*WORD2).*\n\K(?-s).*WORD2
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/KuNJ1c/1).

**Details**:

- `(?s)` - a DOTALL modifier ON (`.` matches line break chars)
- `^` - start of string
- `(?=.*WORD1)`  - there must be `WORD1` somewhere in the string
- `(?=.*WORD2)` - there must be `WORD2` somewhere in the string
- `.*` - any 0+ chars, as many as possible, up to the last occurrence of the subsequent subpatterns (if you use a lazy `*?` quantifier, `.*?` will match 0+ chars as few as possible up to the *first* occurrence of the subsequent subpatterns)
- `\n` - a newline
- `\K` - match reset operator discarding the currently matched text
- `(?-s)` - DOTALL mode disabled (`.` does not match line breaks)
- `.*WORD2` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as many as possible, and then `WORD2`.

Comment: See [`(?s)(?:\G(?!\A)|^(?=.*WORD1)(?=.*WORD2)).*?\n\K(?-s).*WORD2` modification](https://regex101.com/r/wdEQ2t/1) if you need to get multiple matches with this approach.

Comment: Thanks, I extend it to three words with this [`^(?=[\s\S]*WORD1)(?=[\s\S]*WORD3)(?:[\s\S]*\n)?\K.*WORD2`](https://regex101.com/r/18BiHE/3)

Comment: Ok, but `[\s\S]` is not really necessary when you can control `.` behavior with the inline modifiers. It is not JavaScript or Python, where you have no such option.

Answer (score 2):

The question mentions this pattern, which works:

```
ag "WORD2" $(ag -l "WORD1")
```

But only `WORD2` will be highlighted in color. I prefer:

```
ag 'WORD1|WORD2' --passthru -C3 $(ag -l "WORD1" $(ag -l "WORD2"))
```

This gives three lines on either side of the matches and highlights both `WORD1` and `WORD2`.

Answer (score 1):

```
function agmw() {
  args=("$@")
  qs="ag -l  $1"
  for i in {2..$#}; do
    qs="$qs | xargs -r ag -l '${args[$i]}'"
  done
  argarr="$1"
  for i in {2..$#}; do
    argarr="$argarr|${args[$i]}"
  done
  qs="$qs | xargs -r ag '$argarr'"
  echo $qs
  ag '$argarr'
  bash -c $qs
}

agmw hello world #seacrh hello and world across all files
```

Answer (score 0):

> p.s. currently I've managed to using this:  `ag "WORD2" $(ag -l "WORD1")`

That's certainly the easiest way to do it.  The tools you're talking about are inherently line-oriented, and you're looking to match different lines in the same file.

If you use ack, it has the `-x` operator which lets you do `ack -l WORD1 | ack -x WORD2` which is basically the same thing as `ack -l WORD1 | xargs ack WORD2` without having to introduce `xargs` into the pipeline.

Comment: As far as I know the problem with Ack is it doesn't support regexes on multiline cases. For example in your solution I want something like this: `ack -l "regexPatternForMultiLIne" | ack -x "ShowThisValue:"`